# How to implement live video broadcasting in C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, broadcasting

I want to plug a live video broadcasting facility to a website. I'm planning to use silverlight and C# but I'm very newbie in this topic.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I have a camera. I want it to capture it and show on my website. Live. But I have no idea about what I must do inside. Tell me everything about the capturing, streams, api's, dll's, whatever else I need to know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm interested in this question too... Is there any blog posts or books that explain this step by step?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, you may want to consider the free Windows Media Encoder 9 SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/encoder/features.aspx). The idea is that Windows Media Encoder allows you to use any device as a media source (say, a video capture card or a streaming-enabled camcorder) and to push it out as an ASF stream, or even to multicast/broadcast it via Windows Media Services.

The WME SDK is simply a programmatic (COM) interface to WME. In principle you can automate the encoder and instruct it to use your camera as a source, and push it out to a specified UDP port or publishing point (for the latter you'll need Windows Server 2003/2008 with Windows Media Services installed).

A newer alternative is Microsoft Expression Encoder SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9A077A3D-58CE-454C-B486-153F0578BE4A&displaylang=en), which "talks" to Expression Encoder and allows you to stream out to Silverlight clients (among others), but the caveat here is that EE is not free (WME is).

Answer (score 0):

do you have a live stream?  Or is that the part you need?  If you already have a live stream with a URI, then you could use Silverlight to display it as all you need is a player and a URI (you can get a player anywhere, here's one http://sl2videoplayer.codeplex.com).

If you don't have the stream, then what you will need is some mechanism to capture video and stream it.  You can use Windows Media Server to do the streaming.

Can you clarify what pieces you have and what you need?

Comment: The only thing I have is just a camera and I don't know the phases to make it live. It will be great, if you could clarify the phases. Because, I don't know exactly what pieces I need. So thanks!