# Planning to use real time streaming video. Alternatives

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, streaming

Having a site written under `ASP.NET MVC` framework which alternatvies are there to integrate it with `real-time video streaming`?

I've heard about `IIS Smooth Streaming`. Also I've heard that it isn't a good way to use `ASP.NET MVC` here? How this gets resolved in a real world applications?

Thanks!

**Environment (supposed..)**

Windows Server 2008 R2;
IIS 7;

But maybe it is possible to use some service on crossdomain, I mean on other platform which supports the kind of services..

Comment: I don't see how streaming can possibly affect a MVC structure to be honest. I never used IIS Smooth Streaming but it should be fine?

Comment: As I understand it, ASP.NET MVC is server-side only. What you ask about is video streaming and that wouldnt be the script/language of the site, but rather the data-streaming services running. 

Which IIS version are we talking about? which Windows server edition?

Comment: What exactly is your question here, If you want to get started on how to do your streaming, [you have a question here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c)

Comment: Ok. I'll try to explain more precisely. I have a web application (`.NET` platform, `Windows Server`) and I want to let users watch real time broadcasted video using the mentioned/other site. My question is about broadcasting video and web sites more precisely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not using simply Vimeo hosting for your videos? https://vimeo.com/.
It is not free for commercial purposes, but it is cheap enough and it allows high resolution video. Probably it is cheaper that handling streaming on your IIS if you have not a big big traffic ad sveral several videos.

Comment: The thing is that video should be broadcasted live.

Comment: I don't think vimeo offers this type of service. However if you google: streaming video hosting you will find other hosting services that may solve your problem. I think that probably hostinbg is a better solution in most of cases, since video streaming require a lot of internet bandwitdth that you need to purchase if you try to stream yourself

Comment: I agree with you about bandwidth.

Comment: About IIS streaming modes, consider some of them are not a standard and they works just with a silverlight player...but now html5 player compatibility is required. Don't forget to verify this if you decide to have your own streaming

Answer (score 0):

I've found this thing, similar to my question: [How to implement live video broadcasting in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608141/how-to-implement-live-video-broadcasting-in-c). Still searching for alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check ASPNET Video ? http://www.aspnet-video.com/